# Is listing an interfaces members good documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I've not noticed this anywhere else but [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/4411/interaction-with-web-element#t=201609211538130709907) consists of lists of interface members as part of the documentation:

[image]

It does have *usage* underneath, which seems much more useful and inline with the *use examples* idea. But the list on the top seems unhelpful. Intellisense gives you all this information. It doesn't feel like documenting it is much use.

Should I edit this and remove them? or is this ligitimate?

Comment: I'd say it's not an example, so it should be gone. Also that information is readily available on MSDN, so one could just link to that (which is more likely to be up-to-date anyway.

Comment: I thought the syntax and parameters section was for lists like this.

Comment: Hmm... it _might_ make sense if each entry linked to relevant usage cases below, but as it stands now, that list looks a bit redundant when the information is already available on the MSDN, as @MikeMcCaughan said.  Looks like it needs to be fixed, IMO.  Don't know all that much about C#, though, so take what I'm saying with a grain of salt.